# How to pass in parent instance on creation of a nested record in rails console?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, entity-relationship, nested-resources

I'm mucking around in rails console and I've gotten myself stuck trying to do something pretty simple.

`Quote_requests has_one Quote` belonging to it.

In the Quote init method I've declared that it needs to take three arguments, none of which is the parent Quote_request. The models are created within rails with the correctly defined relation statements on each side.

I am trying to play around with the objects in rails console to create a new quote on a quote_request, and `Quote.new(arg1, arg2, arg3)` returns a non initialized quote object;

```
=> #<Quote:0x007fb64471b978 not initialized>
```

Because i guess it's breaking the defined relations in the rails app because it should `belong_to` a `Quote_request` instance and I've not passed in/connected it to a quote_request instance. I have a quote_request instance all created and ready, but I cannot call;

my_quote_request.quote.new(arg1, arg2, arg3)

Can you help me sort myself out on this simple but fundamental relation, object and message passing exercise.

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if you defined Quote_request has_one Quote make sure the one that has an "id" is quote, so in you can check from your schema file the model Quote has quote_request_id

and the way parent(Quote_request) create child(Quote), you can check from this site http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Associations/ClassMethods.html

as an sample

```
@quote_request = QuoteRequest.new
@quote = @quote_request.create_quote(arg1, arg2, arg 3)
```

Comment: Thanks @widjajayd, your answer and that link were very helpful.